# Java says "file does not exist" when using absolute path

Tags: java, file, relative-path

I'm working on a very simple project that's supposed to open an image with the windows video player when run. However, I've encountered a problem. I want to have it be able to access the file "snp.jpg" with a relative file path, so it will work on computers other than my own. But, when I have it set to a absolute file path, it fails and tells me that "the file ... does not exist". Any Ideas?

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
    import java.io.File;



public class openpic {

    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception

    {


        File f = new File ("C:\Users\charl\Desktop\Computer Science\JavaProjects\src\snp.png");
        Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
        d.open(f);
        System.out.println("imageviewer open;");



    }

}
```

Comment: try this:  C:\\Users\\charl\\Desktop\\Computer Science\\JavaProjects\\src\\snp.png

Comment: check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html

Answer (score 2):

(Ops... fixing the answer, after I read the text above the code)

The relative path will start from the directory you run the program. Also called *current working directory*.

Also, as you are using Files, try to use the NIO API, with Path. Like:

```
Path filePath = Paths.get("./snp.png")
```

With this API, you can check the working directory using:

```
filePath.toAbsolutePath()  
// just print it then, or check with a debugger
```

---

Also, be careful about the slashes.

When using Windows and this slash `\`, you need to make them double: `\\`.

Other option is to invert it: `/`.

Answer (score 2):

**Microsoft Windows syntax**

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
 import java.io.File;



    public class openpic {

        public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception

        {

            // Microsoft Windows syntax
            File f = new File ("C:\\Users\\charl\\Desktop\\Computer Science\\JavaProjects\\src\\snp.png");
            Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
            d.open(f);
            System.out.println("imageviewer open;");



        }

    }
```